# Manipulate lists without curly braces

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to use Manipulate to specify a list of numbers on the user side, say {50,60,70,80,90,95,99}, but I don't want the curly braces to need to be in the text entry box. i.e.

```
Manipulate[
(*my code here*),

{{variable,{50,60,70,80,90,95,99}},InputField}
]
```

Has the functionality I want, but I would like to get rid of the curly braces that are displayed in the text entry field.

Comment: Whoops, had to make a small edit to the code.

Comment: `Manipulate[(*my code here*)variable, {variable, {50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
   95, 99}}]
` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using the tracking function in `Dynamic`, which makes managing `TrackedSymbols` easier in `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 variable,
 {{variable, {50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 99}}, InputField[
    Dynamic[
     StringTrim[ToString@variable, "{" | "}"],
     With[{v = ToExpression["{" <> # <> "}"]},
       If[ListQ@v,
        variable = v,
        (* raise exception *)
        ]
       ] &
     ],
    String] &}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe to maximize the experience for the end users, the best way would be to employ the API related functionalities. You may see the following entries:

- [Guide: Creating an Instant API](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CreatingAnInstantAPI.html)
- [Input interpreters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html)
- [API functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html)

You may try using the following construct:

```
Manipulate[Module[{internalvar},
  internalvar=
  Interpreter["Number" | DelimitedSequence["Number"] | 
              DelimitedSequence["Number", {"{", ",", "}"}]][variable];
  (*your code here*)
 ], {{variable, 
  ToString@{50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 99}}, 
 InputField[#, String]&
}]
```

This shall provide a robust interface, for many sort of input.

Screenshots of results:
[image: Input a valid Wolfram list]
[image: Input with out brackets]
[image: Input as space separated sequence]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MMA SE! So, one way to do this is to actually treat the manipulated `variable` as a string, and then parse it into your "real" variable in the code.

So, to do that, we're going to make two quick functions: one to convert lists to strings-without-brackets, and one to convert back.

```
ListToString[l_List] := StringTake[ToString[l], {2, -2}]

StringToList[s_String] := ToExpression["{" <> StringTrim[s,","] <> "}"]
```

In the first, it takes characters `2` to the penultimate one (`-2`), thus excluding the braces at either end, and in the second, it string-joins (`<>`) curly braces at either end and then parses it as a Mathematica expression via `ToExpression`.

You might be wondering why `StringTrim[s, ","]` is in there; that's just to trim off any trailing commas if your user forgets! (E.g. if their input is "1,2,3," and they forgot to delete the last comma; this will take care of that behind the scenes for them.)

So, inside the `Manipulate`, at the start of the code labeled `(*my code here*)` in your question, you'll want to insert the following:

```
realvariable = StringToList[strvariable]; (*my code here*)
```

This will parse your input whenever your user presses `Enter`.

Now change your `Manipulate` variable specification to

```
{{strvariable, ListToString[{50,60,70,80,90,95,99}]}, InputField[#, String] &}
```

Using `InputField[#, String] &` will make `InputField format the string nicely, without quotes.

Also, as a note: it would be wise to put this `realvariable` in a `Module`, so that the variable `realvariable` is trapped inside the manipulate, e.g.

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{realvariable},
    realvariable = StringToList[strvariable];
    (*my code here*)
    ],
  {{strvariable, ListToString[{50,60,70,80,90,95,99}]},
    InputField[#, String] &}
  ]
```

Let me know if it's unclear how any of this works!